# Couldn't understand the behaviour of initial parameter in np.min() function:

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
print('min using where parameter column wise with initial parameter as 10: ',
  np.min([[9,13],[12,11]], where=[False, True], initial=10))
```

**output:**
min using where parameter column-wise with initial parameter as 10:  10

According to my understanding, the initial parameter is something that will be the output value in the output array when the minimum value in the array is greater than the 'initial' parameter value. (In other words, maximum value to printed as output)

But here, it is showing 10 as output even when we have 9 as the minimum value of the array.

Comment: Usually in `ufunc`, the `where` works with the `out` parameter.  I haven't explored how the `initial` plays with this.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, my bad guys.
The thing is I completely forgot about the where parameter, as I have
provided input to the where parameter = [False, True]. so the actual output with the where parameter is 11. So it is printing 10 as output.